# Align Content inside a Div

Tags: html, css

### **WHAT I HAVE**

I have this Table.

[image]

With this **HTML**

```
<div class="list-item">
<p>
 <input type="checkbox">
 <span class="list-type"><img src="/images/types/{{this.type}}.png" title="{{this.type}}" /></span> 
 <span class="list-title">{{this.title}}</span> 
 <span class="list-owner">{{this.owner}}</span>
 <span class="list-date">16 Dec 2014</span>
</p>
 </div><br>
```

With this **CSS**

```
.list-item{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #dddddd;
}

.list-type{
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

### WHATH I WANTO TO ACCOMPLISH

But i want to create something like a table inside the `<div>`.

**NOTE** I KNOW that a `<table>` fits perfect, but for how this content is beign created i need to simulate a table with this `<div>`, so table unforntannly its not an option here.

I need to replicate something like this (check image).

[image]

**NOTE** ignore the Star icon

### WHAT I ALREADY TRY

---

Settin `margin-left` to each of the `<span>` but the order of the "admin" and "date" are not equals, if i use margins i get this (check image).

[image]

Im getting this with this **CSS**

```
.list-item{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #dddddd;
}

.list-type{
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.list-title{
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.list-owner{
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.list-date{
  margin-left: 190px;
}
```

Comment: You need to use a table for this, or display: table, row, etc, on existing elements.

Comment: Hi @imgonzalves thanks for the comment, like i say <table> is not an option here, because the content {{this.something}} is created dynamic so if i use table inside the template it will create N numbers of tables, for example if i have 10 documents the template rendered will create 10 diferrents tables, i cant change this behavior because this is something the apps already have in production, so i need to find the way to "simulate" a table inside a <div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed some Tags and some CSS, I like the use of percentage width and divs. If this does not help you maybe it can give you more ideas.

```css
.list-item{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #dddddd;
}
.cb{
    float: left;
    width:3%;
}
.list-type{
    float: left;
    width:8%;
}


.list-title{
    float:left;
    width:35%;
}

.list-owner{
    float:left;
    width:15%;
}

.list-date{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item">
<p>
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
 <div class="list-type"><img src="/images/types/{{this.type}}.png" title="{{this.type}}" /></div> 
 <div class="list-title">Title</div> 
 <div class="list-owner">Owner</div>
 <div class="list-date">16 Dec 2014</div>
</p>
 </div><br>
<div class="list-item">
<p>
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
 <div class="list-type"><img src="/images/types/{{this.type}}.png" title="{{this.type}}" /></div> 
 <div class="list-title">Title22</div> 
 <div class="list-owner">Owner22</div>
 <div class="list-date">16 Dec 201422</div>
</p>
 </div><br>
<div class="list-item">
<p>
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
 <div class="list-type"><img src="/images/types/{{this.type}}.png" title="{{this.type}}" /></div> 
 <div class="list-title">Title 333</div> 
 <div class="list-owner">Owner 333</div>
 <div class="list-date">16 Dec 2014333</div>
</p>
 </div>
```

Did this help???

Comment: I am really happy. Go go go. Work... :)

Answer (score 3):

Try CSS tables:

```css
.list-item {
  display: table;
}
.list-item > p {
  display: table-row;
}
.list-item > p > * {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below css:

```
.list-title{ margin-left: 10px; width: 200px;}
.list-owner{ margin-left: 10px; width: 40px;}
.list-date{ margin-left: 10px; width: 40px;}
```

**Note**: Change the width size according to your need.

Answer (score -2):

Tabular data: use tables.

Or as @oriol suggested, use CSS tables.